# Standard placement order for common buttons

Tags: user-interface, button, standards

I know that in Microsoft Windows, OK/Cancel buttons normally appear in this respective order. On the other hand, in Linux distros, I often saw Cancel/OK instead.

What about (Yes/No), (Yes/No/Cancel), (Add/Edit/Remove) and other common buttons?

Is there any standard placement order for these?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Microsoft [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511268.aspx#commitButtons):

> Right-align commit buttons in a single row across the bottom of the
>   dialog box, but above the footnote area. Do this even if there is a
>   single commit button (such as OK).
>
> Present the commit buttons in the following order:
>
> 1. OK/[Do it]/Yes
> 2. [Don't do it]/No
> 3. Cancel
> 4. Apply (if present)
> 5. Help (if present)

From the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BACJGAAI):

> The buttons at the bottom right of a dialog all dismiss the dialog. A
>   button that initiates an action is furthest to the right. This action
>   button confirms the alert message text. The Cancel button is to the
>   left of this button.
>
> If there’s a third button for dismissing the dialog, it should go to
>   the left of the Cancel button. If the third button could result in
>   data loss—Don’t Save, for example—position it at least 24 pixels away
>   from the “safe” buttons (Cancel and Save, for example).
>
> A button that affects the contents of the dialog itself, such as
>   Reset, should have its left edge aligned with the main dialog text or
>   if there is a Help button, 12 pixels to the right of it.

From the [Java Look and Feel Design Guidelines](http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed2/book/HIG.Dialogs2.html):

> If a dialog box has a default button, make it the first command button
>   in the group. For example, in languages that read from left to right,
>   the default button is the leftmost button.

Some of the above conflict with one another.  You may also find that the advice conflicts with the vendors own applications.  However, I would follow the guidelines for your operating system of choice and stick with them.  At least that way you have consistancy within your own output and hopefully the vast majority of other apps on your platform.

Comment: Archived Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines: https://web.archive.org/web/20161013015954/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742499.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft recommends one, Apple another.

Survey here shows 50/50 split:
http://measuringuserexperience.com/SubmitCancel/index.htm

This page has also links to official UI guidelines, which answer your question for some OSes.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 50/50. It was 50/50 for one spacing and 74/26 for the other. An argument could be made that even 50/50 shows a strong preference for OK-on-the-right given that a large majority of the participants are likely Windows users and so are accustomed to OK-on-the-left.